# Cannot populate ListView getView is not called

Tags: java, android

I am trying to populate a listview with input data i take from user.

AddPostPage is where i take data from user.I dont see any error messages and postList is not empty.Just getview is not called and i cant see any entry in listview.Since listview is not in addpostpages activity(its in another layout forum_entries.xml) maybe thats the problem ?

```
public class AddPostPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    String categoryName;
    private EditText titleInput;
    private EditText bodyInput;
    PostAdapter adapter;
     ListView postlistview;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.forum_user_post);
        categoryName = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("incomingcategory");
        View forum_entries = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.forum_entries, null, false);
         postlistview = (ListView) forum_entries.findViewById(R.id.categoryPostsListView);

        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        titleInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleInput);
        bodyInput =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bodyInput);
        add.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Post post = new Post(titleInput.getText().toString(),bodyInput.getText().toString());

                if(categoryName.equals("CS 201")){
                    List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();
                    postList.add(post);
                    Log.d("test",postList.get(0).getTitle()); //working

                    adapter = new PostAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.post_row, postList);

                    postlistview.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                }






            }
        });
    }


}
```

This is the PostAdapter:

```
public class PostAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {
    private List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<Post>();
    private Context context;

    private int layoutResource;

    public PostAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, List<Post> posts) {
        super(context, layoutResource, posts);
        this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
        this.postList = posts;
        this.context = context;
        Log.d("adater",posts.get(0).getBody());
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
Log.d("getview","getview"); // not called.
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            Log.d("bos","bos");
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
        }

        Post posts = getItem(position);
Log.d("posts",posts.toString());

         Log.d("test","postlar bos degil");

            TextView postTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView postBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.body);
            postTitle.setText(posts.getTitle());
postBody.setText(posts.getBody());






        return view;
    }




}
```

Post Class:

```
public class Post {


    String title;
    String body;

    public Post(String title,String body){

        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;


    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }


}
```

post_row.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

forum_entries.xml (listview that i am trying to populate is here)

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/categoryPostsListView"
        android:layout_width="339dp"
        android:layout_height="382dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/categoryName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"></ListView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_entry_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/categoryPostsListView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Add Entry"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you chec if this is true? categoryName.equals("CS 201")

Comment: yes i checked its working

Comment: Your log values getting the output?

Comment: the one which is in adapters constructor is giving output but getview is not giving output

Comment: did you manage to mae this work?

Comment: no i added listview in same layout that way it works without problemm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a different layout in your onCreate method that the one where the listview is:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.forum_user_post);
        categoryName = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("incomingcategory");
        View forum_entries = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.forum_entries, null, false);
         postlistview = (ListView) forum_entries.findViewById(R.id.categoryPostsListView);
```

The layout inflated by the activity is `forum_user_post.xml`, but your list view is in `forum_entries.xml` aparently. Your activity had another layout so that's why you were not seeing the listview.

Try setting the correct layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.forum_entries);
postlistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.categoryPostsListView);
```

Or simply bring your listview to `forum_user_post.xml` as it's where most of your views are. If you do that, then use:

```
setContentView(R.layout.forum_user_post);
postlistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.categoryPostsListView);
```

If you want to keep the list in another layout file, no problem, but you need to include it in the main layout file, use the include tag inside the forum_user_post.xml file:

```
 <include layout="@layout/forum_entries"/>
```

Comment: then how do i reach button and edittext which is in forum_user_post ?

Comment: You'd need to have them all in the same layout, take the listview to forum_user_post and user it as the one inflated by the activity.

Comment: so isnt it possible to populate a listview from another layout ??

Comment: No, setContentView tells the activity which layout file it needs to display, even though you inflated the layout for the listview the activity won't be able to know that. You can have a separe layout file for your list view, but it needs to be included (use the include tag) in the main layout file

Comment: You can: 1) Bring the listview to the same layout as the buttons and use one layout file, 2) Use the include tag to include the listview layout file inside the main layout file

Comment: if i do include everything overlaps... isnt this stupid there must be another way ???

Comment: I'd need to see our forum_user_post.xml file to help you more